# HP Wifi not working in Ubuntu 19.04 in Secure Boot

Tags: ubuntu, hp-pavilion, secure-boot

Output of lspci:
`00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 08)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Intel(R) 100 Series Chipset Family LPC Controller/eSPI Controller - 9D4E (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
01:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Topaz XT [Radeon R7 M260/M265 / M340/M360 / M440/M445] (rev 83)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168NGW [Stone Peak] (rev 10)`

I have dual boot of Windows 10 and ubuntu 19.04.
My Wifi icon is missing in ubuntu if I boot with Secure Boot enabled.But it works perfectly if it is disabled.
In case of windows Wifi works perfectly irrespective of whether it is in secure boot or not.

My Wifi adapter is:Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168NGW.
Model No:HP 15g br106tx.

Edit:It was working fine for 4 months before this problem occured.

[Output of sudo lshw -C network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBVPR.png)

Comment: Not all Ubuntu drivers are 'signed' and therefore get blocked https://askubuntu.com/a/1020094/ by Secure Boot.  Please click [edit] and tell us which WiFi adapter the PC uses (or the model number of the HP PC from the serial number sticker) and which Ubuntu driver it uses. Please do not click Add Comment; instead, please use [edit].